# R: Handy user interface to subset data displayed on a plot

Tags: r, user-interface, plot, subset

I am trying to build a simple user interface that allows the user to decide what subset of the data he/she wants to be displayed on a plot.

Here is a very silly trial of mine

```
require(ggplot2)

x = runif(1e5,1,10)
a = rep(0:9,each=1e4)
b = rep(1:10,1e4)
y = x^(a/b)

DATA = data.frame(a=a,b=b,x=x,y=y)

dummy=FALSE
while(TRUE)
{
    response = readline("Do you want to continue? (n/y): ")
    while (response!="y")
    {
        if (response=="n") {dummy=TRUE;break}   
        response = readline("Do you want to continue? (n/y): ")
    }
    if (dummy) break

    a_sub = readline(
        paste0("What subset for 'a' do you want?: (",paste(unique(DATA$a), collapse=","),") ")
    )
    b_sub = readline(
        paste0("What subset for 'b' do you want?: (",paste(unique(DATA$b), collapse=","),") ")
    ) 
    print(ggplot(data=subset(DATA,a==a_sub & b==b_sub), aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point())
}
```

It works but isn't really convenient. There might exist much better solution though, where the user could select the desired value through mouse clicking. Can you please make an example of a nice interface that works my purpose?

Comment: [Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/). Or do it client-side with [plotly](http://moderndata.plot.ly/new-feature-dropdown-menus-in-plotly-and-r/) if you're a little brave. Or maybe [manipulate](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/627_e9264c581fde4fa4ad9d4e9353031226.html) locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try `ggvis`. Drawing from [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/davis-rug/VGkYICK694A):

```
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)
DATA %>% 
  ggvis(~x, ~y) %>%
  filter(a == eval(input_slider(0, 9))) %>%
  filter(b == eval(input_slider(1, 10))) %>%
    layer_points()
```

[image]